# How do you redirect to a page after someone presses a button? The meta tag lets you do only with seconds

Tags: html, redirect

I'm creating a website in which there is a lot of linking involved. I don't know how I should redirect to other pages on clicking of buttons like how you would sign up and it would redirect you to a login page or a homepage. Something like that. A lot of buttons involved. The meta tag lets you redirect after a certain amount of seconds but in my case, I don't know how many seconds it would take for the user to sign up. What are my options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to learn a Backend Framework, I use Django and Flask(Nodejs is also a popular one), Using Django it becomes very easy to redirect between webpages and log in and signup becomes very easy, go with flask if you are good at python or go with nodejs if you are good at javascript, Django is like an advance version of flask
Here is the link for Documentation

[Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/)

[Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com)

[NodeJs](https://nodejs.org/)